# FFMPEG scaling watermark

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm currently using a command to add a watermark + scrolling text and some extra encoding options to a video.

The watermark + scrolling text are made to fit correctly when the video is 1280px (width) but when the original video is any other size (for example 1920px) the watermark + scrolling text gets tiny so i need to scale this.

watermark size= 400x48

Current code i'm using

`-i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w):y=(main_h-overlay_h-4)[out];[out]drawtext=fontsize=20:font=tahoma:alpha=0.5:fontcolor=white:borderw=0.8:bordercolor=black:text=THIS IS MY SCROLLING TEXT :y=line_h-4:x=w-(t-300)*w/40" -keyint_min 20 -vcodec libx264 -c:a copy -b:v 1700k -movflags +faststart`

I think that this piece of code `scale2ref=400*iw/1280:48*iw/1280` might do the work but i have no clue where exactly to paste this in. I keep on getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is,

`"[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=400*iw/1280:48*iw/1280[wm][vid];[vid][wm]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w):y=(main_h-overlay_h-4),drawtext=fontsize=20:font=tahoma:alpha=0.5:fontcolor=white:borderw=0.8:bordercolor=black:text=THIS IS MY SCROLLING TEXT :y=line_h-4:x=w-(t-300)*w/40"`

For fontsize, if `20` is acceptable for width `1280`, then use expression `fontsize='20*main_w/1280'`

Comment: While this command works perfect used with https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-batch/


  

Using it on my server does not work for some reason.
Using ffmpeg version 3.4.2 with --enable-libfreetype

Is this ffmpeg version outdated?

Comment: I've added the log to my question above. @Gyan

Comment: Don't add the label `out` at the end. See my filtergraph.

Comment: Apologies, I actually did used it without label "out" but pasted the wrong output here when i tested it with "out"
It gives the same error output. See edited log. @Gyan

Comment: Put `THIS IS MY TEXT` in quotes. Try both single and double.

Comment: The quotes did not help but replacing `font=tahoma` with `fontfile=/full/linux/path/to/fonts/fontname.tff` fixed it!